# Why list = [0] return false only in first input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this piece of code:

```
name = [0] 
while True :
        # The name needs to be entered twice
        yourname = input("Enter your name: ")
        name.append (yourname)
        if name[-2]:
            print("YOU DID IT")
            break
        else:
            print("REPEAT")
```

This code works great. But I still don't understand this code :

1. In order for first input to print "REPEAT" why `name = [0]`? why if I change the code to `name = []` it's show error?
2. Why  `name = [0]` return false in this code ?

From my understanding `if name [-2]` will check if there is value or not at `name`, so if the code `name = []` it should return false and print "REPEAT".

Comment: Sorry if i asked a lot and it sound like i'm asking for tutorial but i don't. I searched at python tutorial and didn't found the answer as to why name = [0] return false but not name = []

Comment: name = [] =>empty list (len(<list>) = 0) . If len(<list>) == 0, then if <list> will return False.
name = [0] => non-empty list (len(<list>) = 1). If len(<list>) > 0, then if <list> will return True.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Agree SO isn't a tutorial site. But SO encourages newbies and contributors should support them. The question is programming based. Would have appreciated if you had provided some pointers to the user on where can he find additional help.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Pretty crude way of writing the code. But see if this helps in understanding.

Initially:

```
name = [0]
len(name) = 1
```

1st iteration

```
name = [0, "Foo"]
len(name) = 2
name[-2] = 0
if name[-2] => if 0 => False => REPEAT
```

2nd iteration

```
name = [0, "Foo", "Foo"]
len(name) = 3
name[-2] = "Foo"       # name[1]
if name[-2] => if "Foo" => True => YOU DID IT => break from the loop
```

Comment: So it's false because the elements is zero ?

Comment: but why if i input zero twice it changed to true ?

Comment: 0, empty string, empty list, empty dict evaluates to False in python.

Answer (score 0):

1. In Python, providing negative integer index `i` (in this case -2) to a list will return the i-th element from the end. 
   When you initialize list with `name = [0]` and then input your name (say "Derrick"), list is now `name = [0, "Derrick"]` which means that `name[-2] = 0`.
2. When you initialize list as `name = []`, after first input the list is `name = ["Derrick"]` and `name[-2]` is out of index which returns an error.
3. `if name[-2]` does not check if there is value in the list at that index or not. Your code is working because Python considers `0` as `False`. Thus, `if name[-2]:` is same as `if False:`.

Try initializing your list as `name = [False]` and `name = [True]`, it will make things clearer.

If you want to check the number of elements in a list, use `len(name)`.
You can use something like:

```
name = [] 
while True:
    yourname = input("Enter your name twice : ")
    name.append (yourname)
    if len(name) == 2:
        print("YOU DID IT") 
        break
    else:
        print("REPEAT")
```

Comment: I think you might also want to insert a condition to check if the two inputs are same.

Answer (score -1):

```
if name[-2]:
```

This checks if the 2nd element from the end of the list exists.

If you initialize `name=[]`, in the first iteration, there will be only one element in the list. Hence it will show list index out of range error.